# Favicon showing up in multiple Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I'm having an unusual problem - I uploaded a favicon into one of my rails applications into the application.html.erb file into the head using this code: 
`<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>`. This works fine, the favicon shows up, but when I close that application and open a new one into my localhost:3000, the same favicon is showing up, but there's no code in that application for it, in the head nor in the public/favicon file. Any idea how this can be happening?

Comment: I think this is a browser issue rather than a problem with specific to Rails. Do you see the same problem after clearing cache / when using a different browser?

Comment: `<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>`, did it mean that file is in `public` folder?

Comment: @Tom You're right, this did seem too strange to be a Rails-related problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because of the cached version on browser for address `localhost:3000` i.e. `127.0.0.1:3000`. Try changing the port number to something else. For example: `localhost:3001` by running this command:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

You won't see the same favicon now.